# Python analyze requests

Tags: python, http

I'm interested in building an app that lets developers see http/https requests from their machine real time. Something like firebug, but it catches requests made not only from a browser but also a shell. My question is, is there any python packages that allow me to tap into the module that makes each request ? I'm not very clear as to what this is called but its basically like firebug or wireshark.

Comment: On Linux you could use a TUN/TAP device.  TUN will let you grab IP traffic, then you could parse up to the http level.  http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such activities are often referred to as [packet sniffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer). See [Packet sniffing in Python (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462439/packet-sniffing-in-python-windows)

Comment: Thanks, both links were very helpful.