# Python - How to view *all* HTTP connections coming in/out of my machine?

Tags: python, http, logging, monitor

I know of the library requests, and urllib, and logging. However, from the examples I've perused, I can only seem to find the example where you specify a specific example - e.g. - `requests.get('https://httpbin.org/headers')`. Is there any way to continuously and actively monitor all incoming/outgoing connections, regardless of HTTP verb?

(I believe wireshark or fiddler can do this, but I am writing a program in Python and do not want any sort of wireshark or fiddler python extension.)

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @PedroLobito Mac osx

Comment: You should  be able to use https://github.com/pynetwork/pypcap.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [`pypcap`](https://github.com/pynetwork/pypcap):

**Installation:**

```
pip install pypcap
```

---

**Usage 1** :

```
import pcap
sniffer = pcap.pcap(name=None, promisc=True, immediate=True, timeout_ms=50)
addr = lambda pkt, offset: '.'.join(str(ord(pkt[i])) for i in range(offset, offset + 4))
for ts, pkt in sniffer:
    print('%d\tSRC %-16s\tDST %-16s' % (ts, addr(pkt, sniffer.dloff + 12), addr(pkt, sniffer.dloff + 16)))
```

**Usage 2**:

```
import dpkt, pcap
pc = pcap.pcap()     # construct pcap object
pc.setfilter('icmp') # filter out unwanted packets
for timestamp, packet in pc:
    print dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(packet)
```

---

**Notes:**

- If you're on windows, make sure you check the [windows installation notes](https://github.com/pynetwork/pypcap#windows-notes)(you'll need to install the [npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) library).
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/462497/797495

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sufficient reputation to comment, but the first code snippet didn't work for me on Python3. Maybe because I installed pypcap with the workaround [here](https://github.com/pynetwork/pypcap/issues/105), I didn't need to invoke `ord` because the values in `pkt` were already integers. So my code was:

```
import pcap
sniffer = pcap.pcap(name=None, promisc=True, immediate=True, timeout_ms=50)
addr = lambda pkt, offset: '.'.join(str(pkt[i]) for i in range(offset, offset + 4))

for ts, pkt in sniffer:
    print('%d\tSRC %-16s\tDST %-16s' % (ts, addr(pkt, sniffer.dloff + 12), addr(pkt, sniffer.dloff + 16)))
```